# How would one compare two parse tree to find ambiguity in a Context Free Grammar by using Z3 solver?

Tags: z3

Example Grammar:

```
E ::= E + E | n
```

I need to prove that the grammar is ambiguous due to the following two paths:

```
E -> E + E -> E + E + E -> n + E + E
E -> E + E -> n + E -> n + E + E
```

The idea is that one would compare the functions "sets" symbol1(symbol,index,time) (for a specific time t) and symbol2(symbol,index,time) - finding where they are equivalent - however having a different predecessor (i.e at time t-1)

The problem is I have no idea how to compare the two functions symbol1 and symbol2

I can post the code, if you're interested .... (its about a page and half worth, but that might be inappropriately long?).

The code is written in Z3Py.

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether a CFG is ambiguous is undecidable in general. However, if you restrict the number of rule applications to a small number, then you can try generating all possible strings with that many applications and check whether you can reach the same string using a different number of steps. In any case, I don't think SMT solvers would be a good fit for this kind of problem since the number of strings derivable can grow exponentially with number of steps; which would require you to keep the number of steps to a very small number, making the problem uninteresting.

Of course, if you know some property of the grammar in advance, then you can come up with a custom algorithm to take advantage of it. (Say if it's LALR(1) parseable.) But even in that case other algorithmic methods would be better compared to an SMT based solution.